# I am new to hadoop and learning the basics. I installed sandbox recently, but I am not able to run the Hadoop command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# hdfs dfs -ls
ls: `.': No such file or directory
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]# hdfs dfs -mkdir mayank
mkdir: `mayank': No such file or directory
[root@sandbox-hdp ~]#
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayank, while listing files in hdfs it is always suggested that you use "/" eg: hdfs dfs -ls / so see all the directories in the hdfs root and then descend accordingly. As you are a beginner using hdfs dfs -ls would be bit hard to understand what is listed without even specifying the path. As cricket mentioned if no  in hdfs list command then it will list the files in hdfs user directory or the user who has keytab in a secured cluster.

Comment: This is great...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
hdfs dfs -ls
```

By running this as root, you have no `/user/root` folder, you must make this.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir mayank
```

You have no `/user/root/` folder, so no directory can be made within it.

You should instead do `hdfs dfs mkdir -p /user/root/mayank`, then both will work

---

As commented, `root` won't have HDFS permission by default to create directories. You would need to `sudo su - hadoop`, for example, (or any HDFS superuser), then run the `mkdir` command

Comment: This is correct. You might not be able to create home directory as root user though. You'll need to execute something like: "sudo -uhdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/root/mayank". And then: "sudo -uhdfs hdfs dfs -chown -R root /user/root" to make root the owner

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help..hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/root/mayank worked for me... now I am able to make directory and list it.